# Don't drop rows on a coldfusion query of queries join

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion

I find I'm dropping values in coldfusion when doing a query of queries from two datasources if the same value isn't present in both queries. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
<cfquery name="query1" datasource="Master" > 
  SELECT keyval as foo, otherVal FROM table1
</cfquery> 

<cfquery name="query2" datasource="External" > 
  Select keyval as foo, otherVal2 FROM table2
</cfquery> 

 <cfquery name="GetJoinedData" dbtype="query">
      SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
      query1, query2
      WHERE query1.foo= query2.foo
   </cfquery>
```

table1 will always have at least all of the record table2 has, so my data might look like this

```
table1
keyval   otherval
 a         120
 b         121  
 c         122
 d         124
 e         125   

table2
keyval   otherval2
b          xx
c          xx
```

And I'm looking for

```
foo       Otherval  otherval2
 a         120
 b         121         xx
 c         122         xx
 d         124
 e         125
```

As you can guess, the GetJoinedData query drops off any records not in both tables. I think the solution would be to add "Dummy" records to query2 to account for the records query1 has that it doesn't, but I don't know an efficient way to go about it.

Comment: What are you doing with `joinQuery`? You don't use it so is it even relevant to the question?

Comment: You are querying `WHERE query1.foo= query2.foo` so records that do not satisfy that will be omitted. Some sample datasets would probably help to illustrate your problem.

Comment: @MT0 I was trying to boil down my code for the question and accidentally left that in. Removed it.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg Having looked at it - `OUTER JOIN` is not possible in Query of Queries but one technique for mimicing an `OUTER JOIN` is to use the `joinQuery` method you had in the question initially (which at first glace looks irrelevant to the question but is actually helpful).

Comment: @MTO's approach is the same one I use, but there is still a problem.  Because you are selecting *, you are going to have at least on field that is in both queries, foo.  This will not throw any errors, but the ambiguity could cause ColdFusion to give you unexpected results.  Laziness has it's place, but you are overdoing it here.

Comment: @DanBracuk I don't select * in the actual code, I just typed the example that way. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since query of queries does not support `OUTER JOIN`s you can do (using `joinQuery` from the [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34633647/1) of the question):

```
<cfquery name="joinQuery" dbtype="query" >
    SELECT *
    FROM   query2
    WHERE  1 = 0  -- get the table structure but zero rows.
</cfquery>

<!--- Add a row of NULL values --->    
<cfset QueryAddRow(joinQuery) />

<cfquery name="GetJoinedData" dbtype="query">
  SELECT *
  FROM   query1, query2
  WHERE  query1.foo = query2.foo
  UNION
  SELECT *
  FROM   query1, joinQuery
  WHERE  query1.foo NOT IN (#QuotedValueList(query2.foo)#)
</cfquery>
```

The above will give you `query1 LEFT OUTER JOIN query2`.

You could also do it without using a query of queries:

```
<cfquery name="GetJoinedData" datasource="Master">
  SELECT t1.keyval AS foo1,
         t1.*,
         t2.keyval AS foo2,
         t2.*
  FROM   table1 t1
         FULL OUTER JOIN -- or LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         table2 t2
         ON ( t1.keyval = t2.keyval )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Upvote for suggesting to handle this with a SQL query instead of using QoQ.

Comment: This did work, for some reason I had to change <cfqueryparam value     = ValueList(query2.foo) to <cfqueryparam value     = #ValueList(query2.foo)#

Comment: @MT0 will I run into any issues with a maximum length on the cfquery param? I checked the coldfusion documentation and it wasn't specific.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg Updated - `<cfqueryparam ... />` seems to not match the rows... however, using `#QuotedValueList(...)#` in the query does work.

Comment: `<cfqueryparam value=ValueList(query2.foo) list="yes" />` does not work but, strangely, `<cfqueryparam value="#ValueList(query2.foo)#" list="yes" />` does... so you could still use parameterised queries.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg maximum length of the cfquery param is 2100 if we have a list value more than 2100, We should simply use this valueList() without cfquery param.

Comment: Now that you have solved the problem with Query of Queries, you might want to look at the sql solution again.  If both databases are oracle, you might be able to set up a database link.

Comment: @DanBracuk Unfortunately, one is oracle and the other sql2008.